# What exactly is the meaning of 起 in 只要关闭起大门？

Tags: meaning-in-context

> 只要关闭起大门，四合院内便形成一个封闭式的小环境。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 14.

What is the meaning of 起？

I am here:

只要(as long as)关闭(close)起(starts)大门(the big door).

But I am really perplexed since the 只要(as long as) has duration, while the 起(starts) happens once, so I cannot make it have sense.

Answer (score 2):

Compared with 关闭起大门，we use 把大门关闭起来 more often.

In this structure, 起 or 起来 is used after a verb as supplementary to express taking action, starting to do something. Here come a few examples:

走起！ Let us go.

唱起来！ Start to sing!

走起来，走起来，不要停！ Move! Move! Do not stop!

他很难过，但是他没有哭，反而唱起歌了。 He was sad, but he did not cry, instead he started to sing songs.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase consists of 3 parts - 只要(As long as)关闭**起**(closes **up**)大门(the gate), which is equivalent to "只要(As long as)关闭(closes)大门(the gate).

Comment: I wonder if you'd accept 关闭上 as a perfectly equivalent synonym in this sentence (and, if not, why not).

Comment: Yes, it is acceptable. Actually, in both cases, 闭 is highly redundant.  关上大门 = 关起大门 = close up the gate.

Answer (score 1):

Actually 起 in this sentence sounds a little stilt for native Chinese speakers for 闭 and 起 both serve as a complement which is grammatically false. As you can see in the picture [image: here], this kind of connection is almost non-existent in Baidu, which is  the most used search engine in China. Therefore this sentence is a sick one for standard Chinese, or rather an abusage.

Comment: "關(閉)起來" is used exclusively in closing the physical things that have a gap between the parts such as doors and windows - 把窗户關(閉)起來, 把電腦蓋子關(閉)起來, 把電源關(閉)起來....  The word "關閉" in your examples is strictly used as a verb which means "close down" to end something.

Comment: I only wantant to stress that "關閉起" (including "關閉起來") is an odd expression, try to use "把……關起來""關閉……" as a better substitution for it.

Comment: I agree. 閉 is redundant on most occasions  (see comment under my answer).